# How to subscribe to multiple work items in the Azure Board?

Tags: azure-devops

For example, I have 20 tasks in the current sprint. As the scrum master, I want to receive updates on all the 20 tasks? How can I subscribe to all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to stack Overflow!

The [Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST API would help stay informed about activity in Azure DevOps projects. To elaborate, the Notification APIs primarily provide the ability to create and manage subscriptions.

You might want to check out the [Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/subscriptions?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) REST API that Azure DevOps has. A subscription defines the conditions by which a user or team should be notified, and where notifications should be sent. A subscription can be just for you, or if you are a team admin, can be shared by everyone in the team.

Here is an example you can refer to to [follow a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/subscriptions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#follow-a-work-item).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is [bulk editing multi-selected work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/bulk-modify-work-items?view=azure-devops#bulk-edit-multi-selected-work-items), by adding a tag:

[image]

An then create a subscription as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Notification ([Manage your notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)) like that:

[image]

and update it for each new (current) iteration.